# Property not found on object of type

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ситуация следующая. Изучаю Obj-с для iOS, как-то заговнокодил до рабочего состояния программу, недавно решил её несколько видоизменить и улучшить, используя старые наработки. Переписал интересующий меня модуль, начал переносить рабочий код остальных, и наткнулся на такую ситуацию.
Есть класс:

```
    @interface SelectUserViewController ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *newsList;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedUser;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *news;

    @end

    @implementation SelectUserViewController
    @synthesize name;
    @synthesize selectedUser;
    @synthesize news;
    @synthesize newsList;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
        }
        return self;
    }
...
```

Который используется в коде:

```
#import "SelectUserViewController.h"

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    SelectUserViewController *detailViewController = [[SelectUserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectUserViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.selectedUser = [[self.news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    detailViewController.news = self.news;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Компилятор матерится на detailViewController.selectedUser и detailViewController.news - property not found on object of type. Собственно вопрос - почему он их не видит?

Comment: Попробуйте переписать строчку:
@interface SelectUserViewController ()
на 
@interface SelectUserViewController : NSObject

Comment: @interface SelectUserViewController () - Это приватная категория, следовательно все методы приватные и их не видно из вне.

Comment: Черт, забыл указать, что код приведен из .m файлов, в .h файле SelectUserViewController'a написано @interface SelectUserViewController : UIViewController @end. Разве этого недостаточно и надо прописывать в .m файл то же самое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше свойство описано в расширении класса, потому его и видно только в единице трансляции.

Починить вашу ситуацию можно двумя способами:

##### Вариант первый.

Вынести расширение класса в отдельный хэдэр и подключать его там где он нужен

```
// SelectUserViewController_Private.h
@interface SelectUserViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *newsList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedUser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *news;

@end
```

и в нужном контроллере

```
#import "SelectUserViewController_Private.h"
#import "SelectUserViewController.h"

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

##### Вариант второй.

Вынести нужные свойства в публичный интерфейс класса, в хэдэр

```
// SelectUserViewController.h
@interface SelectUserViewController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *newsList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedUser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *news;

@end
```